# Visual studio 2010 dialog halts automated build

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, build-automation

I am working on a project with a build that is automated using NAnt.  The automated build includes NAnt tasks to clean the machine, including deleting and re-creating the virtual directory, clearing out VSWebCache, etc.  Once the machine is reset, it attempts to compile the site with this:

```
<exec program="${visualstudio.install.dir}\devenv.com" commandline="SolutionFile.sln" failonerror="true"/>
```

The problem is that the automated build locks up at this point.

If I open the .sln file interactively, the first thing that happens is Visual Studio prompts me with a dialog box.  I suspect this dialog box is "opening" (invisibly) when I run the NAnt script and I can't click on it to proceed.

The dialog message is:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio

The web (URL) is currently configured for use with ASP.NET 1.1.  Web project (name) is targeting ASP.NET 4.0; if not configured some features may make incorrect assumptions, and pages designed with the tool may not render correctly.

Would you like the site to be configured for use with ASP.NET 4.0?
```

I do in fact have 3 different versions of .NET on my machine-- I work on multiple projects.  I can't configure the site ahead of time because the build script will blow away my configuration anyway.  I guess what I need is either an automated way to accept the dialog (as if I clicked the YES button) or a NAnt task that will automatically set up the vdir to be an ASP.NET 4.0 application.

I do have free reign to modify the build script as I see fit, but I cannot simply remove the portion that resets the machine-- our build box is shared with other projects and we have to reset everything to a known good state before running our compile.

Answer (score 0):

Use MSBUILD directly, don't use devenv. It's the full IDE, and all you need is to build.